# CUDA : Bad performance when allocating heap inside kernel

Tags: c++, c, cuda

As title, I ran a performance test with my NVDIA Tesla M2090. The only thing I did was create new object insider kernel, nothing more. And the result I got was terrible which make me so surprise. Here's my code:

```cpp
template <class T> 
class TArray
{
protected:
    int m_Size;
    int m_Capacity;
    int m_GrowBy;
    T* m_pData;
public:
    template <class T> 
    __host__ __device__ TArray<T>::TArray(int growby)
    {
        m_Size = 0;             // empty to start
        m_Capacity = 0;         // remember the size
        m_GrowBy = growby;
        m_pData = NULL;
    }
}

struct Rect2D
{
    real64 left;
    real64 top;
    real64 right;
    real64 bottom;
};

class GERect2D : public Rect2D  
{
public:
    __host__ __device__ GERect2D() {
        left   = 0;
        top    = 0;
        right  = 0;
        bottom = 0;
    }
}

class GELineString
{
protected:
    GERect2D* m_pMBR;
    TArray<Point2D>* m_parrPoint;
    bool m_bContain;
    bool m_bRTree;
    TRTree<int32, real64, 2> *m_pRT;
public:
    __host__ __device__ GELineString(int32 growby = 100) {
        m_parrPoint = new TArray<Point2D>(growby);
        m_pMBR = new GERect2D();
        m_bContain = false;
        m_bRTree = false;
        m_pRT = NULL;
    }
}

//My kernel
__global__ void kernel_BuildTree() {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x* blockDim.x;
    GELineString *pLs = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        pLs = new GELineString(17);
        delete pLs;
    }
}

void main() {
    kernel_BuildTree<<<1,128>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The result which I never think about when I ran it is about `18` seconds, while it's only not over 1 milisecond when I ran in CPU. Moreover, when I increased the number in `for loop` to `10,000` (just 10 times from `1000`), the time I got was not `180` seconds (10 times from 18 seconds) as I was expected, it was about 10 minutes

I've read a lot about the warp divergence, occupancy, memory hierarchy of GPU but still can't explain it, so confuse

Any idea?

Comment: Is it actually possible to allocate memory on the device, from the device? I wouldn't have thought so. Maybe CUDA decides to run everything on the CPU instead.

Comment: Memory allocation is slow. Everywhere. Don't use it in performance critical code. That's it. No big science.

Comment: @talonmies:that answer was from 2011, nothing change or any improvement upto now ?

Comment: @immibis: yes, from CC 2.0 it can

Comment: @HoangThong: Not significantly, no. Parallel malloc is extremely difficult to do safely *and* fast. It makes sense to use it if you can amortise the cost over the life of you data - if your compute job takes 10 minutes of GPU time and the memory setup takes 10 seconds, it makes sense. If your compute job takes 10 seconds of GPU time, obviously it doesn't.

Comment: @talonmies : not relate to this question but do you know any data structures library about RTree, BTree, BTree+, ... implemented in CUDA?